# Big quantity of data with MySql

Tags: mysql, multithreading, qt, android-sensors, bigdata

i have a question about `Mass storage`. Actually, i'm working with 5 sensors which sends a lot of datas with a different frequency for each one and i'm using `MySQL DATABASE`.

so here is my questions:

1) is `MySQL` the perfect solution.
2) if not, is there a solution to store this big quantity of data in a data base?
3) I'm using `Threads` in this and i'm using `mutexs` also, i'm afraid if this can cause problems, Actually,it seems to be.

i hope i will have an answer to this question.

Comment: May you precise "a lot of datas" ? Maybe you can use a message queue to do this (Apache Kafka for example), the program just send data to the MQ and a consumer insert them in a DB after. And to store the data, you can consider using a NoSQL database if you don't need relational features, I don't know what your data looks like so it's hard to advise you.

Comment: sorry for this! but when i said "a lot of datas" i meant "a huge quantity of data" and it's about the real time data storage. Also i need to analyze them.
So can you, please, give me more information about this "MQ" and the advantages and disadvantages of "MQ" in this case.
And Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql is good solution for OLTP scenarios where you are storing transactions to serve web or mobile apps. But it does not scale well (despite of cluster abilities).

There are many options out there based on what is important to you:
File System: You can device your own write-ahead-log solution to solve multi-threading problems and achieve "eventual consistency". That way you don't have to lock data for one thread at a time. You can use schema-full files like CSV, Avro or Parquet. Also you can use S3 or WSB for cloud based block storage. Or HDFS for just block and replicated storage.

NoSql: You can store each entry as document in NoSql Document stores. If you want to keep data in memory for faster read, explore Memcached or Redis. If you want to perform searches on data, use Solr or ElasticSearch. MongoDB is popular but it has scalability issues similar to MySql, instead I would chose Cassandra or HBase if you need more scalability. With some of NoSql stores, you might have to parse your "documents" at read time which may impact analytics performance.

RDBMS: As MySql is not scalable enough, you might explore Teradata and Oracle. Latest version of Oracle offers petabyte query capabilities and in-memory caching.

Answer (score 0):

Using a database can add extra computation overhead if you have a "lot of data". Another question is what you do with the data? If you only stack them, a map/vector can be enough.
The first step is maybe to use map/vector that you can serialize to a file when needed. Second you can add the database if you wish.

About mutex if you share some code with different thread and if (in this code) you work on the same data at the same time, then you need them. Otherwise remove them. BTW if you can separate read and write operations then you don't need mutex/semaphore mechanism.

Comment: first, thank you for this.
Actually, it is not only stacking data, but also analyze them.
about mutex, i did the same thing, i mean i work with mutex to prevent that two threads storing in the same ressource in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data anywhere, but the data storage structure selection would depends on the use cases (the things, you want to do with the data).
It could be HDFS files, RDBMS, NoSQL DB, etc.
For example your common could be: 
1. to save the sensor data very quickly. 
2. get the sensor data on the definite date.
Then, you can use MongoDB or Cassandra.
If you want to get deep analytics (to get monthly average sensor data), you definitely should think about another solutions.
As for MySQL, it could also be used for some reasonable big data storage, 
as it supports sharding. 
 It fits some scenarios well, some not. 
But I repeat, all would depend on use cases, i.e. the things you want to do with data. 
So you could provide question with more details (define desired use-cases), or ask again.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
For the moment, i need to work with MySQL, store and Analyze data in the real time handling.

Comment: What kind of real time analyzing?

Comment: here is an example:
when i get data from those sensors, i would like to handle this data to compare them with another data which come from the interface of my application.
i can do this without using database, but i need to store data coming from sensors in the database, first, then analyze them by another handlers and all of this should be in the real time.

Comment: If your want to store sensor data (timeseries) and your real-time analysis should be based on current values or daily values, I can recommend Cassandra as a database. See [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling).

Answer (score 0):

There are several Questions that discuss "lots of data" and [mysql].  They generally say "yes, but it depends on what you will do with it".

Some general statements (YMMV):

- a million rows -- no problem.
- a billion rows or a terabyte of data -- You will run into problems, but they are no insurmountable.
- 100 inserts per second on spinning disk -- probably no problem
- 1000 rows/second inserted can be done; troubles are surmountable
- creating "reports" from huge tables is problematical until you employ Summary Tables.

Two threads storing into the same table at the "same" time?  *Every* RDBMS (MySQL included) solves that problem *before* the *first* release.  The Mutexes (or whatever) are built into the code; you don't have to worry.

"Real time" -- If you are inserting 100 sensor values per second *and* comparing each value to one other value:  No problem.  Comparing to a million other values: big problem with *any* system.

"5 sensors" -- Read each hour?  Yawn.  Each minute?  Yawn.  Each second?  Probably still Yawn.  *We need more concrete numbers to help you!*